# Elbow Topology Tips

Tags: modeling, animation, topology, retopology

This isn't exactly a question, but I'm still seeking help.
I don't think my elbow topology is good for animation. Here is it looks like in edit mode
[image]

and here's how it looks like in pose mode just a little bit bent

[image]

[image]

I tried other elbow topology and they all get weird results. I wouldn't mind this elbow if the clothes were going to hide it but that's not the case.
I'd also like to say I can't sculpt my character and retopo it later because my unit can't handle it so I spent weeks learning how to model the whole body.
Is there a way to get better results? Does this have anything to do with shapekeys?
I'd like to ask for some tip on better topology. Getting a little frustrated :'>

Edit1:

[image]

and here is the result. Rather decent improvement here except for the streak thing near the elbow pit.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that I have ever seen elbow done as you tried, I always go for this and it always works well enough with good weigh painting: https://sk.pinterest.com/pin/12736811434803276/

Comment: I think its the same concept but in the pin there's 2 redirecting loops, if that's the term. I will try to replicate it @MikoCG

Comment: another way would be just to make a square with one face, insert one face inside with I and divide it be Ctrl+R into 4 parts like this(or to make less polys, only 2 parts):https://www.reallusion.com/character-creator/includes/images/base/topology/10-cc3-base-plus-topology-knees.jpg (I use this for knees for most of times)

Comment: @MikoCG I think the main issue im having now is the inner elbow. Idk if it's normal the they go through each other.

Comment: the topology will always clip over itself in rigs like this. You can only try to control it better with weight painting, you know the only way to not ever get over clipping mesh would be to create a whole muscle system(but that's for big companies, not individuals)... another way I could recommend you to watch Royal Skies on youtube, he creates quick and short videos on this manner and most of my skills are from his videos (also model he uses is free to download and you can use it as reference

Comment: @MikoCG Thank you. I have found a video from Royal skies this made me realize I have to focus on studying rigging because Ive just been using rigify.